# I don't want to install the browser addon for gnome extesions by any means, how to install a gnome extension?

Tags: gnome

How to install a gnome extension without the browser addon?

Comment: @Esther not an obvious phrase for search in google, but okay, I'll check thanks

Comment: I actually searched for "install gnome extension manually" or something like that, with `site:askubuntu.com` in order to get answers here (because I was sure there was one somewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your past history that you are using v22.04

If not already installed on your system, install `Extension Manager` from Ubuntu Software.

Using that utility, you will be able to install extensions specific to the GNOME desktop environment used in this release.

Select `Browse` to find the extensions you'd like to make use of. Simply toggle the switch to turn that installed extension off if no longer required and the cog icon to adjust its properties.

[image]

Comment: It hanged at the first run and ShellTile is not supported in 22.04 but it worked, thanks a lot!